# How to get column name and first row value from table in javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I would like to somehow save the column name and value of the first data in the row to variables Row, Column and than send it to update_table.php in which I update table. I can do it but only if I pass var newContent(changed value of selected cell). I put // in front of non-working code lines. Also, how would line:

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","update_table.php?newContent="+newContent,true);
```

look like with 2 more parameters(Column,Row)?

```
    $(function () { 

     $("td").dblclick(function () { 
     var OriginalContent = $(this).text(); 

    $(this).addClass("cellEditing");
    $(this).html("<input type='text' value='" + OriginalContent + "' />"); 
    $(this).children().first().focus(); 

    $(this).children().first().keypress(function (e) { 
        if (e.which == 13) { 
            var newContent = $(this).val(); 
            //var Row = $(this).parent().find('td');
            //var Column = $('#pregled1 tr th').eq($(this).index()); //pregled1 is a name of the table

            $(this).parent().text(newContent); 
            $(this).parent().removeClass("cellEditing");



        ///////////////////SEND TO update_table//////////// 
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
            xmlhttp.open("GET","update_table.php?newContent="+newContent,true);
            xmlhttp.send();

        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////        
        } 
    }); 

    $(this).children().first().blur(function(){ 
        $(this).parent().text(OriginalContent); 
        $(this).parent().removeClass("cellEditing"); 
    }); 
}); 

});
```

Here is the table:

```
<?php

 header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

 include("config.php");

        print("<table class='pregled1' id='pregled1'>");
        $query = "SELECT * FROM radovi WHERE vrsta_kolegija='diplomski' ORDER BY ime_prezime ASC";
        $result = mysqli_query($link,$query);

        ////header of the table////
            print("<tr><th>JMBAG</th>");
            print("<th>IME I PREZIME</th>");
            print("<th>LOK.MAT.BR.</th>");
            print("<th>KLASIFIKACIJSKA OZNAKA</th>");
            print("<th>URUDŽBENI BROJ</th>");
            print("<th>ODABRANI KOLEGIJ</th>");
            print("<th>ODABRANI MENTOR</th>");
            print("<th>PRVI IZBOR</th>");
            print("<th>PRVI MENTOR</th>");
            print("<th>DRUGI IZBOR</th>");
            print("<th>DRUGI MENTOR</th>");
            print("<th>MENTOR D.Z.</th>");
            print("<th>STUDENT P.Z.</th>");
            print("<th>ZADATAK PREDAN</th>");
            print("<th>NAPOMENA</th></tr>");

        while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){


            print("<tr>");

            print("<td>".$row["jmbag"]."</td>");
            print("<td>".$row["ime_prezime"]."</td>");
            print("<td>".$row["lok_mat_br"]."</td>");
            print("<td>".$row["klas_ozn"]."</td>");
            print("<td>".$row["uru_br"]."</td>");
            print("<td>".$row["odabrani_kolegij"]."</td>");
            print("<td>".$row["odabrani_mentor"]."</td>");
            print("<td>".$row["kolegij1"]."</td>");
            print("<td>".$row["mentor1"]."</td>");
            print("<td>".$row["kolegij2"]."</td>");
            print("<td>".$row["mentor2"]."</td>");
            print("<td>".$row["ch1"]."</td>");
            print("<td>".$row["ch2"]."</td>");
            print("<td>".$row["ch3"]."</td>");
            print("<td>".$row["napomena"]."</td>");
            print("</tr>");

        }
        print("</table>");
 ?>
```

Comment: unrelated tip you should consider storing `this` and `$(this)` to more meaningful variables. It is really hard to follow scope currently.

Comment: hey ,, can you paste the table or html structure that you have so we can follow?

Answer (score 1):

why not use jQuery since it seems like you already have it in the project.

`$.get('update_table.php', {column: 'col 1', row: 'row 1'}).done(function(data){});`

you could then remove the code you have relating to IE6 and 7 as well
since jQuery should handle that internally.

https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/

Answer (score 0):

The line that you need to send two pars is this:

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","update_table.php?newContent="+newContent+"&row="+rowvalue,true);
```

Thanks for html,, hope this will help you! I made a jsfiddle to take a look

http://jsfiddle.net/aoak63dL/

this is the most needed part to you I think..

```
$('td').on('click', function(){
    var inx = $(this).index() ;
    var hdr = $(this).closest('table').find('th').eq(inx).text();
})
```

Comment: seems like with "$(this).index():" i get value 0 every time.